# Cron job to auto commit changes in git repository always fails on Linux server

Tags: bash, cron, cronie

On a server, I want to auto commit all changes of predefined git repositories every hour. And like every cron job of mine, it should send an email with stdout and stderr to me if it fails (I use msmtp for it).

This is the cronjob:

`59 */1 * * * git-auto_commit.sh 2>&1 | msmtp address@domain.tld`

The content of git-auto_commit.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

git_path="$HOME/git_repos"
repo_array=( 
  "repo1" 
  "repo2" 
  "another_repo" 
)

eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

if [ -e ~/.ssh/my_private_key ]
then
  ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_private_key
fi

for repo in ${repo_array[@]}
do
  if [ -d $git_path/$repo ]
  then
    echo "##############################"
    echo "Current repos: " $repo
    cd "$git_path/$repo"
    if [[ $(git status --porcelain) ]]
    then
      git pull 
      git add -A 
      git commit -m "automated commit"
      git push 
    else
      echo "No changes found"
    fi
    echo "##############################"
  else
    echo "The path $git_path/$repo doesn't exist"
  fi
done

eval $(ssh-agent -s -k)
```

The output looks similar to this:

```
Agent pid 16469
Identity added: /home/username/.ssh/my_private_key
##############################
Current repos:  repo1
No changes found
##############################
##############################
Current repos:  repo2
No changes found
##############################
Agent pid 16469 killed
```

The cronjob works and I can pull all changes on my local machine, but I get an email every hour (it should only mail me stdout and stderr if it fails). If I execute git-auto_commit.sh it executes without problems.

Why does it send me an email every hour?

Comment: I guess that it will depend on the exit status of the script... which will be what is run _last_ in the script.... so, `eval $(ssh-agent -s -k)`... what is the exit status for that call? https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html#:~:text=The%20exit%20status%20is%20used,the%20conditional%20and%20list%20constructs.

Comment: `echo $?` shows 0 after the last command :(

Comment: Oh! You are piping.... the second command will run regardkess. Are you expecting to run only if ghe first fails? Then it should be `||` instead of `|`.